# Bluemix : duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 with IMFCore framework

Tags: mobile, push, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobile-services

I am trying to integrate IBM Push notification with my mobile first app. 
I am using `xcode 7` and `objective c` . 
But with IMFCore framework, i am getting error like `duplicate symbols for architecture arm64`

here are the error details:

```
 /.../.../../../../.../IMFCore.framework/IMFCore(WLHTTPClientResponse.o)
    /.../../../../../.../WorklightSDK/libWorklightStaticLibProject.a(WLHTTPClientResponse.o)
ld: 153 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, adding Bluemix push to a Foundation application is not supported. However, the development team has been working on a Swift SDK for Bluemix Mobile Services which allow the integration to MFPF without the duplicate symbol errors.

See Jaalger's answer:

[Duplicate symbols in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation (MFP) and Bluemix IMFCore SDK's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862821/duplicate-symbols-in-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-mfp-and-bluemix-imfco)